# Python matching values in 2 list of dictinaries - fastest solution

Tags: python

I have 2 lists of dicts with products.
The first list contains dicts with products info (some basic information  + stocks)
The second list contains dicts with products prices.
I need to merge the dictinaries based on the 'product_code' field. My lists contains 200k+ products. Is there a way to make it faster?

```
merged_list_of_dicts = []
for price in prices:
    for stock in stocks:
        if price['product_code'] == stock['product_code']:
            dict_ = {}
            dict_['product_code'] = price['product_code']
            dict_['price'] = price['price']
            dict_['stock'] = stock['stock']
            all_together_list.append(dict_)
            break

return all_together_list
```

Comment: Sort the lists in advance according to the produce_code - 
`prices = sorted(prices, key = lambda x: x["product_code"])` (and same for stocks)

Comment: @TomRon I tried your solution for a lot of products. test_my_solution function took 8346557.458 ms
test_your_solution took 15187222.718 ms

Comment: Another approach maybe worth trying is to load it to pandas table and then merge the tables based on `product_code`. Code should be something like - `prices_df = pd.DataFrame(prices) stocks_df = pd.DataFrame(stocks), mergedDf = prices_df.merge(stocks_df, on="product_code")`

Comment: @TomRon you saved me a lot of time... Thank you. I tried to use pypy, speed was upgraded about 60-70%. It was still very slow. Your solution: test_pandas function took 999.663 ms.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the lists in advance and if they match 1:1 you can iterate them together -

```
prices = sorted(prices, key = lambda x: x["product_code"])
stocks = sorted(stocks, key = lambda x: x["product_code"])
merged_list_of_dics = []
for p, s in zip(prices, stocks):
    dic = {}
    dic['product_code'] = price['product_code']
    dic['price'] = price['price']
    dic['stock'] = stock['stock']
    all_together_list.append(dic)

return all_together_list
```

Comment: No, they are not 1:1. I will use proposed solution above. Thank you for your time